# Why does pyzmq subscriber behave differently with asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, zeromq, publish-subscribe, pyzmq

I have an XPUB/XSUB device and a number of mock publishers running in one process. In a separate process, I want to connect a subscriber and print received message to the terminal. Below I will show two variants of a simple function to do just that. I have these functions wrapped as command-line utilities.

*My problem is that the asyncio variant never receives messages*.

On the other hand, the non-async variant works just fine. I have tested all cases for ipc and tcp transports. The publishing process never changes in my tests, except when I restart it to change transport. The messages are short strings and published roughly once per second, so we're not looking at performance problem.

The subscriber program sits indefinitely at the line `msg = await sock.receive_multipart()`. In the XPUB/XSUB device I have instrumentation that shows the forwarding of the `sock.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, channel.encode())` message, same as when the non-async variant connects.

**The asyncio variant (not working, as described)**

```py
def subs(url, channel):
    import asyncio

    import zmq
    import zmq.asyncio

    ctx = zmq.asyncio.Context.instance()
    sock = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
    sock.connect(url)
    sock.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, channel.encode())

    async def task():
        while True:
            msg = await sock.recv_multipart()
            print(' | '.join(m.decode() for m in msg))

    try:
        asyncio.run(task())
    finally:
        sock.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)
        sock.close()
```

**The regular blocking variant (works fine)**

```py
def subs(url, channel):
    import zmq

    ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
    sock = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
    sock.connect(url)
    sock.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, channel.encode())

    def task():
        while True:
            msg = sock.recv_multipart()
            print(' | '.join(m.decode() for m in msg))

    try:
        task()
    finally:
        sock.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)
        sock.close()
```

For this particular tool there is no need to use asyncio. However, I am experiencing this problem elsewhere in my code too, where an asynchronous recv never receives. So I'm hoping that by clearing it up in this simple case I'll understand what's going wrong in general.

My versions are

```py
import zmq
zmq.zmq_version()  # '4.3.2'
zmq.__version__  # '19.0.2'
```

I'm on MacOS 10.13.6.

I'm fully out of ideas. Internet, please help!

Comment: Since you are out of ideas, try catching exceptions and see if it gives any more information. Maybe confirm if regular zmq and asyncio zmq mix are supposed to work, or if the whole thing needs to be asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks Harsh. I pulled out all logging calls before posting, for clarity. I'm quite sure that client code waits forever on the async recv. The publisher process I mentioned is written using asynchronous zmq sockets, so the only working situation is async and non-async. I don't see how that should matter though. Surely if the publish process is the same, it shouldn't matter what connecting clients are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working async variant is

```py
def subs(url, channel):
    import asyncio

    import zmq
    import zmq.asyncio

    ctx = zmq.asyncio.Context.instance()

    async def task():
        sock = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
        sock.connect(url)
        sock.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, channel.encode())

        try:
            while True:
                msg = await sock.recv_multipart()
                print(' | '.join(m.decode() for m in msg))
        finally:
            sock.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)
            sock.close()

    asyncio.run(task())
```

I conclude that, when using asyncio zmq, sockets must be created with a call running on the event loop from which the sockets will be awaited. Even though the original form did not do anything fancy with event loops, it appears that the socket has an event loop different from that used by `asyncio.run`. I'm not sure why, and I didn't open an issue with pyzmq because their docs show usage as in this answer, without comment.

**Edit** in response to a comment:

`asyncio.run` always creates a new event loop, so the loop presumably created for the sockets instantiated outside of the co-routine passed to `asyncio.run` (as in the asyncio variant in the original question) is obviously different.

Comment: *...the socket has an event loop different from that used by asyncio.run - I'm not sure why* - zmq likely uses `asyncio.get_event_loop()` internally to find out the "current event loop" when invoked, and continues to submit events of interest to that loop. Since `asyncio.run()` creates a fresh event loop, the loop is guaranteed to differ from the one obtained previously. It is best to organize the code so that everything asyncio-related (other than imports) is run from the function invoked by `asyncio.run()` (or functions invoked by that function, and so on, just not ones before it).

Comment: Thank you @user4815162342! I should have noticed that asyncio.run _always_ creates a new event loop. That clears it all up!